# .htaccess redirect URL to sub-part of URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect URLs (100's of them) of a site based on a pattern match.

So for example if the requested url is

```
http://www.example.com/showcase/properties/boston/page/1
```

I would like to redirect it to

```
http://www.example.com/showcase/properties/boston
```

i.e. remove the `/page/1` from the actual url.

I am newbie with all .htaccess concept. So if I have missed any information to add please let me know. Also I would appreciate if somebody can point me to a nice tutorial/book for .htaccess learning.

Thanks very much in advance.

P.S. - The site is built using PHP language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule (.*)/page/(\d+)  $1
```

I don't know any tutorial about .htaccess!
I have apache manual on my PC and I use it!

Comment: Hello ASeman - thanks for the quick reply. I tried the RewriteRule you  mentioned in your comment and it did worked but partially. The rule removed  the /page/1 from the URL but the new redirect url was not correct. It was like this http://www.example.com/home/smartlive/example.com/showcase/properties/boston. Am I missing anything? Once again thanks

Comment: @cjain1443 if you want external redirect, you should put http:// in begining like: http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1

Comment: Aseman - sorry if I was not clear in my comment before. Its not an external redirect. I put the example live with your rewrite rule http://www.jainchetan.com/showcase/properties/boston/page/1. I want this url to redirect to http://www.jainchetan.com/showcase/properties/boston.  But if you visit url http://www.jainchetan.com/showcase/properties/boston/page/1 - the resulting redirect url has some extra top level directories. Any idea how can I get rid of them? Thanks

Comment: It worked Aseman!. I set my RewriteBase to root and your ruled worked like charm. thanks a lot once again - Cj